# how to link a new user to google analytics property/view using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-api-js-client

My requirement is, I need to add a new email id to an existing google analytics account's property.

```js
function insertPropertyUserLink() {
  var request = gapi.client.analytics.management.webpropertyUserLinks.insert(
    {
      'accountId': '123456',
      'webPropertyId': 'UA-123456-1',
      'resource': {
        'permissions': {
          'local': [
            'EDIT',
            'MANAGE_USERS'
          ]
        },
        'userRef': {
          'email': 'liz@gmail.com'
        }
      }
    });
  request.execute(function (response) { // Handle the response. });
}
```

Above code i got from google documentation and i am using the following code for authorization:

```html
<script>
    var GoogleAuth;
    var SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.manage.users';
    function handleClientLoad() {
        // Load the API's client and auth2 modules.
        // Call the initClient function after the modules load.
        gapi.load('client:auth2', initClient);
    }

    function initClient() {
        // Retrieve the discovery document for version 3 of Google Drive API.
        // In practice, your app can retrieve one or more discovery documents.
        var discoveryUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/management/accounts/';

        // Initialize the gapi.client object, which app uses to make API requests.
        // Get API key and client ID from API Console.
        // 'scope' field specifies space-delimited list of access scopes.
        gapi.client.init({
            'apiKey': 'mykey',
            'discoveryDocs': [discoveryUrl],
            'clientId': 'myclientId',
            'scope': SCOPE
        }).then(function () {
            GoogleAuth = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();

            // Listen for sign-in state changes.
            GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

            // Handle initial sign-in state. (Determine if user is already signed in.)
            var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
            setSigninStatus();

            // Call handleAuthClick function when user clicks on
            //      "Sign In/Authorize" button.
            $('#sign-in-or-out-button').click(function () {
                handleAuthClick();
            });
            $('#revoke-access-button').click(function () {
                revokeAccess();
            });
        });
    }

    function handleAuthClick() {
        if (GoogleAuth.isSignedIn.get()) {
            // User is authorized and has clicked 'Sign out' button.
            GoogleAuth.signOut();
        } else {
            // User is not signed in. Start Google auth flow.
            GoogleAuth.signIn();
        }
    }

    function revokeAccess() {
        GoogleAuth.disconnect();
    }

    function setSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        var user = GoogleAuth.currentUser.get();
        var isAuthorized = user.hasGrantedScopes(SCOPE);
        if (isAuthorized) {
            $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Sign out');
            $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'inline-block');
            $('#auth-status').html('You are currently signed in and have granted ' +
                'access to this app.');
        } else {
            $('#sign-in-or-out-button').html('Sign In/Authorize');
            $('#revoke-access-button').css('display', 'none');
            $('#auth-status').html('You have not authorized this app or you are ' +
                'signed out.');
        }
    }

    function updateSigninStatus(isSignedIn) {
        setSigninStatus();
    }
</script>

<button id="sign-in-or-out-button"
        style="margin-left: 25px">
    Sign In/Authorize
</button>
<button id="revoke-access-button"
        style="display: none; margin-left: 25px">
    Revoke access
</button>

<div id="auth-status" style="display: inline; padding-left: 25px"></div><hr>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"
        onload="this.onload=function(){};handleClientLoad()"
        onreadystatechange="if (this.readyState === 'complete') this.onload()">
</script>
```

I have changed the API key and client id with mine and enabled the Analytics API for the app in console. Can anyone help me to integrate the above two code snippets to a single one and can be able to add a new user to analytics property.

Comment: what is wrong with your code as it is?

Comment: Actually, i added the first code snippet into the `if (isAuthorized)` section of `setSigninStatus` function, it is showing error the **gapi.client.analytics is undefined.**

Comment: Related advice, you should strongly consider using the [batch methods](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/user-management#batching) for adding users to a property. There are performance gains and quota incentives when [batching](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/batching) permission API write (delete, insert, update) requests.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this: `**gapi.client.analytics is undefined**`

Change:

```
 `gapi.load(**'client:auth2'**, initClient);`
```

to

```
gapi.load(**'client:analytics'**, initClient);
```

It worked for me.